# read /etc/fstab entries from python

Tags: python

Is there a python package that knows how to parse the `fstab` file?  Perhaps similar to `getmntent(3)` in `linux`.

Admittedly it's not hard to grok that with python (or `awk(1)`, etc.), but I was wondering if that wheel had already been invented.

Comment: https://github.com/ProteinSimple/python-fstab/blob/master/README ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple Google search would have given you this:

https://launchpad.net/python-fstab

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Not sure how my google search failed to find that.  Both the github.com package (see Jon Clements' comment) and this one are currently identical in terms of the python implementation.  The github one includes some debian packaging stuff.  It seems it has been removed as a debian package.

Comment: My google search was: 'get mount point from fstab python'.  Neither the github nor the lp link was on the first page.  Simpler search ('fstab python') is much better.  Sigh.

Comment: Google results vary widely from user to user based on a number of unpredictable factors. The snarkiness was not necessary.

Comment: @Chaim Eliyah There was no snark intended.  You're reading the 'sigh' wrong - maybe more of a melodramatic tongue in cheek.

Comment: @Juan I was talking about the answer, not you. "A simple Google search..." –this assumes everyone gets the same results with Google, when they don't, and theoretical Google results aren't how we answer SO questions. Anyways it's ancient history I was just explaining my distaste.